# How can we call onActivityResult on three classes?

Tags: java, android

In my code there is three class 
I called OnActivityResult in "Activity A"
 then goes to "Activity B" then to "Activity C"
, finally in Activity C i call finish();

by calling finish it doesn't go back to "activity A "

How can i call this?

Comment: What is `mContext ` ?

Comment: sorry am calling finish(); only

Comment: Please help me here activity c is goes back to activity b and then we press backbutton it goes to Acvtivity A

Comment: are you calling ` finish()` in Activity B after starting Activity C?

Comment: No i didnt call where i call finish in activity B

Comment: after calling startAcvtivity for Activity C.try it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call

```
final Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityB.this, ActivityC.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
```

When you are going from ActivityB to ActivityC
on button click or any other click of view in ActivityB